# Questions about indexing in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

As I understand it:

A Clustered Index orders the data physically by the index, so if you use Surname as a clustered index, when you do a select * you will get the surnames in alphabetical order.

A Non-clustered index is not physically reordering your database, but is creating a kind of lookup table that's ordered by the columns you choose.

It says in my book that you can have 16 columns for a clustered index. I'd have thought you'd only be able to choose 1 column though, as it's physically reordering your database by it? Or are multiple columns for if the first column contains duplicates?

Isn't it faster to always use non-clustered indexes, as SQL doesn't have to shuffle the data around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A Clustered Index orders the data physically by the index, so if you use Surname as a clustered index, when you do a select * you will get the surnames in alphabetical order.

That's not necessarily true. An order is not guaranteed unless you supply `ORDER BY` for your query.

> It says in my book that you can have 16 columns for a clustered index. I'd have thought you'd only be able to choose 1 column though, as it's physically reordering your database by it? Or are multiple columns for if the first column contains duplicates?

It sorts lexicographically: first on the first column, then on second (in case of a tie on the first column etc).

> Isn't it faster to always use non-clustered indexes, as SQL doesn't have to shuffle the data around?

Clustered indexes do have some overhead on `INSERT` so it's sometimes advisable to make the tables that require fast `DML` unclustered (like, log tables etc).

However, clustered indexes allow much faster searching on the clustered key which results in faster joins on that key.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of clustered indexes - at least in relation to SQL Server 2005 - is that the ordering of the rows is not actually the physical ordering on the disk. Instead a linked list is maintained, giving a 'logical' ordering to the data. So while there's probably more of an overhead in changing a clustered index than a non-clustered index, it's not going to be as problematic as you imagine.

Comment: That's correct, physical ordering on disk is a completely separate layer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want your clustered index on a unique, narrow, increasing column(s).  You rarely want to cluster on anything which is changing with updates.

Clustered indexes are not really indexes, just the data is stored in a tree instead of a heap.

Non-clustered indexes are generally narrower, so fit more rows per pages and are typically faster for reads (obviously the need to be covering to be useful).